# curl response is different from the responce of java.net.URL

Tags: java, curl

curl -v https://whatwg.org/html

header is:

> HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently 
>   Location: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage

however..

```
String link = "https://whatwg.org/html";
URL url = new URL(link);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
int status = conn.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("Response Code ... " + status);
```

Response Code ... 200

The first and second results are different, what I am doing wrong and how should I receive 301 ?

Comment: I have found the answer.
To receive response like in curl, I should  force the java.net.URL to not follow the redirects. For this need to set up:

`conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);`

After this, I am getting same result as using the curl